# Assistance with variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables

I am a student in my first computer science class. I am trying to figure out how to set the variable so that it takes a number that is attached to a command our teacher set up called ./integerProperties . Please look at the code I have written, I could use some assistance in how to take that input, and plug it into my variable called number.

```
27 │Example output for:  ./integerProperties 1983
28 │
29 │    The number is even:
30 │    false
31 │    The number is odd:
32 │    true
33 │    The number is evenly divisible by three:
34 │    true
35 │    The number is evenly divisible by five:
36 │    false
37 │    The number is evenly divisible by seven:
38 │    false
39 │    How many groups of ten?
40 │    198
41 │    How many groups of hundred?
42 │    19
43 │    The additive inverse:
44 │    -1983
45 │
46 │
47 │
48 │    */
49 │ let firstParameter = CommandLine.arguments[1]
50 │ var number: Int
51 │
52 │ print("The number is even:")
53 │ print(number % 2 == 0)
54 │ print("The number is odd ")
55 │ print(number % 2 != 0)
56 │ print("the number is evenly divisible by 3")
57 │ print(number % 3 == 0)
58 │ print("the number is evenly divisible by 5")
59 │ print(number % 5 == 0)
60 │ print("the number of evenly divisible by 7")
61 │ print(number % 7 == 0)
62 │ print("how many groups of ten")
63 │ print(number / 10)
64 │ print("how many groups of hundreds")
65 │ print(number / 100)
66 │ print("the additive inverse")
67 │ print(number * -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int(String)` to parse the argument to an integer.  Note that if the string is not an integer, it will return a nil `Int?`, and you should handle this case.

```
guard let number = Int(firstParameter) else {
    fatalError("firstParameter is not an Int")
}
```

Edit: You should also check that the parameter even exists, otherwise `CommandLine.arguments[1]` will fail with index out of bounds.

Comment: Just a note, this is not "catch" in the traditional sense - ie: [catching a thrown error](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508). Rather you always get an `Optional` returned from this [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224) and you should always unwrap it.

Comment: Removed the word "catch" to avoid confusion, thanks @ColGraff